# Change Configuration from Ribbon to Spring Cloud Load Balancer in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

I have below configuration for spring cloud gateway with ribbon

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: UserModule
          uri: lb://load-balanced-service-user
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/user/**
ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false
Load-balanced-service-user:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: localhost:9999,localhost:8888
```

Now i want to remove Ribbon and replace with spring cloud load balancer .

I added

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Now what other configuration i need to add in my application.yaml file to switch to spring cloud load balancer ?  I want to add configuration  on .yaml file .I do not want to break old structure with ribbon that is configured in .yaml file .

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the `Hoxton` release train, you will need to set `spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled` to `false`. From what I see, you are using a static list of servers instead of a service registry. In LoadBalancer, you can achieve that by adding a properties-backed [`SimpleDiscoveryClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#simplediscoveryclient). Note that to reproduce the Ribbon's health-check behaviour for such static instances, we recommend the use of the [Instance Health Check mechanism](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#instance-health-check-for-loadbalancer) and disabling loadbalancer caching, since an alternative caching mechanism is provided with the Instance Health check mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for this answer as it helps a lot. In case anyone is stuck on this, I wrote up a prototype for the load balancing without ribbon and service registry [https://github.com/yoonghan/springcloud-gateway]. Welcome for feedbacks and improvements.

Comment: Is this also valid for version `2021.0.0`?

Comment: spring.cloud.loadbarancer.ribbon.enabled -> spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled

Comment: Right, @SoulCub. Fixed the typo.